# when use "Either in fp-ts" for front-end develop?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

tldr : I want to know when to use "either" except network I/O.

In my understanding, Either is used when distinguishing success from fail.

So I use "Either" when network request that may fail.

there are any case other case to use Either in front-end developing ? In a different question, there are any case that may fail ?

thank you

Comment: self-answer : you can use "Either" type when validating form data. if you want to know detail about this, check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=715frtFZjuM

Answer (score 2):

Giulio provides a nice little terse guide for mapping some common problems that arise in imperative code with how they can be dealt with using [fp-ts](https://dev.to/gcanti/interoperability-with-non-functional-code-using-fp-ts-432e). There you will see there network IO challenges are often solved using a [TaskEither](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/TaskEither.ts.html). You will also see that the [Either](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html) type maps well to any synchronous API that may throw.